# Can I stop touchpad to register mouse?

Tags: mouse, touchpad, xfce

Sometimes when I write text with my laptop I touch occasionally the touchpad on my computer because my cerebral palsy. I'm wondering if it is possible to configure Ubuntu such that I can use command line to say when the touchpad should register mouse moves and clicks and when not? I would also like that my USB-mouse would work all the time. I'm using Sony Vaio VPCEB1E, Ubuntu 13.10, and Logitech M185. Here is what `xinput` says:

```
xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Mouse                                id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sony Vaio Keys                            id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 Camera                            id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the mouse settings - type 'mouse' into the dash:
[image]

when your USB mouse is plugged in, you should be able to turn the touchpad off *(it will come back on when the USB mouse is unplugged)*:
[image]

You can also configure the touchpad to be disabled while you are typing, so you don't have problems with it - a very useful feature I find, particuarly for essays, or typing these answers [image]

---

Xfce does allow disabling of the touchpad *(Select the touchpad and untick 'Enable this Device')*, but if you unplug the USB mouse, you can't control the cursor...

But, you can set it to be disabled whilst typing:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I forgot to say that I installed xfce in this machine and I can't find dash in this desktop.

Comment: Should still have mouse settings - wait a sec...

Comment: Updated answer... :-)